# Adding external jar files in Android Studio Project

Tags: java, android, jar, gradle

I added mapsforge versions 0.3.0 and 0.3.1 jar files in my Android Studio project.

Here's my build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
       mavenCentral()
  }
   dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'android'
repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/resources']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')


        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 9
            targetSdkVersion 19
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+')
compile files ('libs/mapsforge-map-0.3.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar','libs/mapsforge-map-0.3.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
}
```

I have this in my gradle.properties

```
#Wed Jun 11 16:12:51 PHT 2014
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.11-all.zip
```

**When i sync gradle:**

**~~~~~~~~Shows this error~~~~~~~**

```
Error:(4, 0) Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'compile()'!**

Possible causes could be:  
- you are using Gradle version where the method is absent (<a href="open_gradle_settings">Fix Gradle settings</a>)
- you didn't apply Gradle plugin which provides the method (<a href="apply_gradle_plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a>)
- or there is a mistake in a build script (<a href="goto_source">Goto source</a>)
```

Please help I'm stuck here for 2 days now.

Answer (score 0):

Put your jar file in the libs folder of your project in the project explorer it should be under -project name-/app/libs/ if it doesn't exist create it.

Then simply put this catch all in your build.gradle.

```
dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

You could also try updating to gradle 1.12 change

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.11-all.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-all.zip
```

Comment: Should I remove the compile files ('file_name.jar','file_name2.jar') or I'll just add the compile fileTree?

Comment: Yes. To be honest I cant really see anything wrong with your gradle code.

Comment: It still cannot detect my jar files.

Comment: Well the last thing I could think of is changing the names of the jar files to be shorter take out any capital letters and white space.